# Find percentages, given percentage difference?

Tags: statistics, percentages

I read a statistic that there is 18% more x than y in a certain group. x + y = 100% of the group

I'm trying to figure out what percentage of the set is x and what percentage is y.

I have found a lot of tutorials on reverse percentages, given the final number and percentage increase, but can't seem to apply it to this.

Thanks

---

**Applying the accepted answer below**, I used simultaneous equation to solve

$$ 1) px + py = 100 $$
$$ 2) px = 1.18py$$

```
Substitue px into equation 1)
```

$$ 1) 1.18py + py = 100 $$
$$ 2.18py = 100 $$
$$ y = 45.87 $$
$$ x = 54.13 $$

I'm assuming that x being 18% greater than y would mean that we find 18% of y and add it to y to find x?
$$ 45.87 + (45.87*.18) = 54.13 $$

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ the only options? i.e. should the percentages of $x$ and $y$ in this group add up to $100\%$?

Comment: Yes there are only two options, and they will add up to 100%

Comment: So if $x$ and $y$ denote the percentages, then we have $x+y=100$ and $x-y=18$. Can you solve this system for $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @Brian Then please write down that fact **into the question itself** because not everybody reads the comments to get **vital** info about a question.

Comment: Ok, I added that info in, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot know what percentage of the set is $x$, because if both $x$ and $y$ increase by the same relative amount, the claim

> There is $18\%$ more $x$ than $y$

is still true.

---

For example, take a group of one million examples.

If there are $118$ examples of $x$ and $100$ examples of $y$, then the claim

> There is $18\%$ more $x$ than $y$

is true. However, if there are $118,000$ examples of $x$ and $100,000$ of $y$, then the claim is **still true**.

---

However, if you know that each element of a set is either $x$ or $y$, then you have **two** equations for the percentage of $x$ and $y$ (let's call them $p_x$ and $p_y$).

1. The first equation tells you that each element is either $x$ or $y$, but not both: $$p_x + p_y = 1$$
2. The second equation tells you that there are $18\%$ more $x$ than $y$: $$p_x = 1.18p_y$$

You have two equations for two variables, so you can easily solve for $p_x, p_y$.

Comment: So there is no answer like:  80% of the set is x, and 20% is y?

Comment: @Brian No, because it could be that 8% of the set is x and 2% of the set is y.

Comment: @Brian Unless you actually **know** that each element in the set is either $x$ or $y$, of course.

Comment: @5xum the OP's comment above says that the percentages of $x$ and $y$ add up to $100\%$.

Comment: @Dave Ah, I see. Well this is a textbook example why you don't put vital information about a question in the f-ing comment section.

Comment: @Brian I now see you wrote in the comment that the percentages of $x$ and $y$ add to $100\%$. This is a **vital** part of the question and it belongs **in the question itself**, not the comments.

Comment: I added a note on applying this solution to find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You know

$$
x = 1.18y .
$$

Can you figure out 
$$
\frac{x}{x+y} ?
$$